# Extract file extension from file path

Tags: r, file-extension, built-in

How can I extract the extension of a file given a file path as a character?  I know I can do this via regular expression `regexpr("\\.([[:alnum:]]+)$", x)`, but wondering if there's a built-in function to deal with this?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that easily found with R basic tools. E.g.:  ??path.

Anyway,  load the `tools` package and read `?file_ext` .

Comment: It doesn't show up with `??"extensions"` although one would have expected that it would.

Comment: @DWin: "patience, grasshopper" :-).   I would also recommend package:sos . It's very cool.

Comment: Witthof: Color me puzzled on two accounts; how does pkg:sos address that lack of appearance of tools::fiie_ext with ??() when a reasonable person would expect it to; and one would certainly need patience obtain value from a search strategy that delivers 20 pages with 400 hits?

Comment: `sos` does a full text search. `??` only searches metadata (title, keywords, etc.) Furthermore, it's not **that** hard to skim the results.  (I tried `findFn("{file extension}")`, `"extract {file extension}"`, and `"{extract file extension}"`, the first was best.)

Comment: This would be more useful with an actual code sample

Comment: @user5359531 Did you read `?file-ext`  ?  one-line code sample is kind of silly

Comment: Note well:  tools::file_ext('foo.csv.gz') return 'gz', not 'csv.gz'

Comment: @ZacharyRyanSmith  Well, that's because the **extension** in your example is "gz" so the code is doing the correct thing.  There's no such concept as "double extensions"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, that's true.  I was just warning people who confound path suffixes with a file's extension (people like me).

Answer (score 30):

Let me extend a little bit great answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/680068/zx8754

Here is the simple code snippet

```
  # 1. Load library 'tools'
  library("tools")

  # 2. Get extension for file 'test.txt'
  file_ext("test.txt")
```

The result should be 'txt'.

Comment: Please scroll up and read the accepted  answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you, Rich! I read this comment and add this code just to show how it looks in the simple code snippet. Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: The other comment may have been first and accepted, but it is nice to see the solution written out. The accepted answer just tells you where you find the answer. This one actually answers the question.

Comment: Don't use `library(tools)` when you can simply use `tools::file_ext`, such as in `tools::file_ext("test.txt")`.

Answer (score 11):

simple function with no package to load :

```
getExtension <- function(file){ 
    ex <- strsplit(basename(file), split="\\.")[[1]]
    return(ex[-1])
}
```

Comment: Nice basic function! Could be one line:`getExtension <- function(file) strsplit(file, ".", fixed=T)[[1]][-1]`. To avoid regex and increase performance `fixed = TRUE` can be used.

Answer (score 4):

The regexpr above fails if the extension contains non-alnum (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions)
As an altenative one may use the following function:

```
getFileNameExtension <- function (fn) {
# remove a path
splitted    <- strsplit(x=fn, split='/')[[1]]   
# or use .Platform$file.sep in stead of '/'
fn          <- splitted [length(splitted)]
ext         <- ''
splitted    <- strsplit(x=fn, split='\\.')[[1]]
l           <-length (splitted)
if (l > 1 && sum(splitted[1:(l-1)] != ''))  ext <-splitted [l] 
# the extention must be the suffix of a non-empty name    
ext
```

}

Comment: The functions `basename` and `dirname` obviate some of the work here

Comment: @Pisca46: I would like to use a function like this in an R package. Did you write the function? If not, could you add a reference in your answer?

Comment: Yes, I wrote  the function myself.

Answer (score 2):

## extract file extension only without dot:

`tools::file_ext(fileName)`

## extract file extension with dot:

`paste0(".", tools::file_ext(fileName))`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any additional package you could try

```
file_extension <- function(filenames) {
    sub(pattern = "^(.*\\.|[^.]+)(?=[^.]*)", replacement = "", filenames, perl = TRUE)
    }
```

If you like to be cryptic you could try to use it as a one-line expression: `sub("^(.*\\.|[^.]+)(?=[^.]*)", "", filenames, perl = TRUE)` ;-)

It works for zero (!), one or more file names (as character vector or list) with an arbitrary number of dots `.`, and also for file names without any extension where it returns the empty character `""`.

Here the tests I tried:

```
> file_extension("simple.txt")
[1] "txt"
> file_extension(c("no extension", "simple.ext1", "with.two.ext2", "some.awkward.file.name.with.a.final.dot.", "..", ".", ""))
[1] ""     "ext1" "ext2" ""     ""     ""     ""    
> file_extension(list("file.ext1", "one.more.file.ext2"))
[1] "ext1" "ext2"
> file_extension(NULL)
character(0)
> file_extension(c())
character(0)
> file_extension(list())
character(0)
```

By the way, `tools::file_ext()` has trouble finding "strange" extensions with non-alphanumeric characters:

```
> tools::file_ext("file.zi_")
[1] ""
```

Answer (score 1):

A way would be to use `sub`.

```
s <- c("test.txt", "file.zi_", "noExtension", "with.two.ext2",
       "file.with.final.dot.", "..", ".", "")

sub(".*\\.|.*", "", s, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "txt"  "zi_"  ""     "ext2" ""     ""     ""     ""
```

Assuming there is a dot - which will fail in case there is no extension:

```
sub(".*\\.", "", s)
#[1] "txt"         "zi_"         "noExtension" "ext2"        ""           
#[6] ""            ""            ""
```

For comparison `tools::file_ext(s)` and the code with inside used regex.

```
tools::file_ext(s)
#[1] "txt"  ""     ""     "ext2" ""     ""     ""     ""    

pos <- regexpr("\\.([[:alnum:]]+)$", s)
ifelse(pos > -1L, substring(s, pos + 1L), "")
#[1] "txt"  ""     ""     "ext2" ""     ""     ""     ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This function uses pipes:

```
library(magrittr)

file_ext <- function(f_name) {
  f_name %>%
    strsplit(".", fixed = TRUE) %>%
    unlist %>%
    extract(2)
 }

 file_ext("test.txt")
 # [1] "txt"
```

Comment: Can you comment how this is an improvement over `tools::file_ext`?

Comment: You'd better use `tools` function

Comment: The proposed function works incorrectly if the file contains dots in the filename. The function splits the filename and outputs the second element, while it should output the last one. For the following filename 'file.name.txt' the output is 'name', not 'txt'. `tools::file_ext` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I've found with no additional packages:

```
FileExt <- function(filename) {
  nameSplit <- strsplit(x = filename, split = "\\.")[[1]]
  return(nameSplit[length(nameSplit)])
}
```