# Splitting a file name into name,extension

Tags: r, split, substring, filenames

I have the name of a file like this: `name1.csv` and I would like to extract two substrings of this string. One that stores the `name1` in one variable and other that stores the extension, `csv`, without the dot in another variable.

I have been searching if there is a function like `indexOf` of Java that allows to do that kind of manipulation, but I have not found anything at all.

Any help?

Comment: Try `tools::file_ext("name1.csv")`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779037/extract-file-extension-from-file-path

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use `strsplit`:

```
R> strsplit("name1.csv", "\\.")[[1]]
[1] "name1" "csv"  
R>
```

Note that you a) need to escape the dot (as it is a metacharacter for regular expressions) and b) deal with the fact that `strsplit()` returns a list of which typically only the first element is of interest.

A more general solution involves regular expressions where you can extract the matches.

For the special case of filenames you also have:

```
R> library(tools)   # unless already loaded, comes with base R
R> file_ext("name1.csv")
[1] "csv"
R>
```

and

```
R> file_path_sans_ext("name1.csv")
[1] "name1"
R>
```

as these are such a common tasks (cf `basename` in shell etc).

Comment: I think the `tools` package is the better way for filename, since the `basename` may also have dots.

Comment: Agreed, I use this internally more and more too.  But note the answer is 4 1/2 years old too :)

Answer (score 8):

Use `strsplit()`:

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html

Example:

```
> strsplit('name1.csv', '[.]')[[1]]
[1] "name1" "csv"
```

Note that second argument is a regular expression, that's why you can't just pass single dot (it will be interpreted as "any character").

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expression, you can do this for example

```
regmatches(x='name1.csv',gregexpr('[.]','name1.csv'),invert=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "name1" "csv"
```