# substring of a path variable

Tags: regex, r

I have a path like this `../some/thing/foobar/foobar.happening` and I want the `character` string between the last `/` and `.`.

I realize this will be easy for some, but I'm not yet familiar with regular expressions etc.
I also probably could do this by myself with `strsplit`, but I'm looking for an elegant one-liner, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173754/splitting-a-file-name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`basename` will give you the part after the last slash.  Then, you can split on the dot (which you have to escape with two `\`)

```
> (name <- basename("../some/thing/foobar/foobar.happening"))
[1] "foobar.happening"
> unlist(strsplit(name, "\\."))
[1] "foobar"    "happening"
```

Then select the first element

```
> unlist(strsplit(name, "\\."))[1]
[1] "foobar"
```

---

I see you actually asked for a way other than `strsplit`.  Here's a regular expression

```
> sub(".*/([^/]+)\\..*", "\\1", "../some/thing/foobar/foobar.happening")
[1] "foobar"
```

- It looks for zero or more occurences of anything `.*`
- followed by a forward slash `/`
- followed by anything that is not a forward slash `[^/]` (inside the brackets, `^` means "not"), one or more times `+`.
- followed by a dot `\\.`
- followed by anything zero or more times `.*`.

Then it replaces that with only the stuff inside the parenthesis `[^/]+` which is everything between the forward slash and the dot.  The `\\1` means the stuff inside the first set of parenthesis.  (there's only one set in this case, but if there were a second we could refer to it with `\\2`)

Comment: ooh great answer! I didn't know about the basename function

Answer (score 4):

You could use a combination of `basename()` and `file_path_sans_ext()`. (The latter comes from the **tools** package, which ships with the basic R distribution.)

```
path <- "../some/thing/foobar/foobar.happening"

library(tools)
file_path_sans_ext(basename(path))
# [1] "foobar"

## Or, if you don't want to load the tools package
tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(path))
# [1] "foobar"
```

Comment: doh! I just recommended that function a couple weeks ago, but I couldn't think of it today.

Comment: +1 for `file_path_sans_ext`. I knew this had to be somewhere. What a terrible name for it, though.

Comment: It's worth taking a quick look at the function def, to see the little bit extra that it does to file names it's handed...

Comment: and the two functions are commuting!