# Split file path into file path and extension in R

Tags: r, string, file

I have written a code that gets the required outcome. I want some help to shorten my code. 
What the code does:

1. Retrieves path of all directories (and subdirectories) that has files in them
2. Splits the lines in two columns - a) one column is the path and b)the other column is the file name with extension

I’m sure there can be a shorter version. Looking forward to the help.

Here is my code:

```
    library(stringr)
    setwd("/Users/Guest/Desktop/Project") #set Working Directory
    path <-"/Users/Guest/Desktop/Project"  #set path to retrieve files
    a <- list.files(path,recursive = TRUE) #retrieve files in variable a
    last <- str_locate(a,"(.*)/") #locate the last "/"
    sub <- str_sub(a,last[,2:2] + 1) #split from the last "/"
    adf <- as.data.frame(a,stringsAsFactors= FALSE) #convert to DF
    colnames(adf) <- "FPath" #ColumnName
    subdf <- as.data.frame(sub, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #Convert to DF
    colnames(subdf) <- "FileName" #ColumnName
    Final <- cbind(adf,subdf) #Join both DF's
    Final <- within(Final, FileName <- ifelse(is.na(FileName), FPath, FileName)) #If there are files directly in root folder (Project), then FileName is NULL so replace it with FPath.
    Final
    write.table(Final, file = "Final_Import2.txt", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep ="\t") #WritetoFile
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173754/splitting-a-file-name)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But my question is not "HOW" to split. My question is whether someone can help me shorten my code. I can get the output with this code, but want to learn the tricks in R. Thanks.

Comment: There a bunch of tricks in the answers linked.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the link. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I'm working on reducing the number of lines. I understand I'm overworking, but thats how it is :(

Comment: What about `basename(list.files(path, recursive=TRUE))` and also check `dirname()`

Comment: Thanks. This helped too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that may be of help aside from the provided answers in the link:

```
library(gsubfn)
m <- strapply(a, '(.*)/(.*)', ~ c(FPath=x, FileName=y), simplify=rbind)
Final <- as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. This definitely does the trick! Thanks for teaching me this.