# Extract extension of file from working directory and check condition

Tags: r, file-extension

**Possible Duplicate:** [Extract file extension from file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779037/extract-file-extension-from-file-path)

I am in a state where i need to check the extension of files in my working directory and take some decision. I check it by `list.files()` and it gives me all the files in the working directory with extension.
I get a list like

```
"GSM18423_PA-D_132.cel"        "GSM18424_PA-D_206.cel"        "GSM18425_PA-D_216.cel"
```

Now further I want a condition, if a file has extension `.cel` do something like below.

```
if(extension==".cel")
...... else
......
```

As i looked for `tools` package, but not working in my R version of `R version 3.1.3 RC (2015-03-06 r67947)` . I tried `install.packages("tools")` which pops up a window and asks to restart my system before installing but finally does nothing even no restart also. Finally i get a message

```
Installing package into ‘/home/hussain/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tools’ is not available (for R version 3.1.3 RC)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract file extension from file path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779037/extract-file-extension-from-file-path)

Comment: @zx8754 . Already mentioned above

Comment: Mentioning it as a duplicate, doesn't make it any less duplicate. This post is a more suitable as a comment to original post.

Comment: @zx8754 You are right. Should not it be asked if not solved from the original post .

Comment: I dont think you need to install `tools`, just load it with `library`. Is this enough to check the extensions: `grepl("*.cel", lst)` (where `lst` is the result from your `list.files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to the comment `@user20650`, i think it would be easy to do something like

```
lst <- list.files()
ext <- grepl("*.cel$", lst)[1]
if(ext)
{ .....
code
....
}else{
....
code
.....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the source-code of `tools::file_ext`

```
function (x) 
{
    pos <- regexpr("\\.([[:alnum:]]+)$", x)
    ifelse(pos > -1L, substring(x, pos + 1L), "")
}
```

just create your own function with this code