# I cant find package tools in cran and github

Tags: r, github, devtools, cran, rtools

I need to include package
`tools` on my shiny app. but I can't find the package in cran nor GitHub, where exactly is it housed. it is already installed on my R but I suspect it was installed as a dependency.

it is the library discussed here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115540

Comment: `tools` is a core package in R, so is installed along with base R and a few other libraries in the R distribution. [Link to relevant R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Which-add_002don-packages-exist-for-R_003f).

Comment: True you got it

Comment: @rpolicastro your comment answered can you edit it into an answer please